# Slightly diagnol swipe will change the tab instead of scrolling. Flutter

Tags: flutter

when I scroll/swipe our app's content some point in time my swipe direction change to diagonal and my tab change instead of scrolling, how I can prevent my tab change on diagonal swipe

Thank you

Comment: You can wrap your widget that hold the content with SingleChildScrollView. Actually, I have never meet such a situation can you share your code

Comment: Can you share your code?